# how to translate c declaration to delphi?

Tags: c, delphi

`typedef void (*funcNetworkEventReceived)(int, unsigned int, int);`

Thanks.

Comment: This question pertains to Delphi. I don't know why the tag was removed.

Answer (score 8):

A void function is a procedure, if we exclude D1, integer is =32bit int, cardinal is 32-bit unsigned.

The calling convention for C is assumed cdecl without export statements, but I assume depending on compiler can be different due to global directives in the file. (if it fails, try stdcall instead of cdecl)

This lands us at:

```
Type 
   TUncNetworkEventReceived = procedure (p1:integer;p2:cardinal;p3:integer);cdecl;
```

Comment: I'd guess TFunc... (not TUnc...) was meant. Typo?